# Extend PATH in Visual Studio for Debugging C# Applications

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We often use 3rd party .DLL's that are wrapped up in our C# applications.   When launching the application from Visual Studio the application is unable to find the .dll.   Is there a way to specify the PATH for a debugging session for C#?

Visual Studio does this quite easily for C++ where you can just go to Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging->Environment

Is there anything similar for C# applications within Visual Studio?

Comment: Only for .NETCore projects (Project > Properties > Debug), a nod to Unix sensibilities. Always avoid DLL Hell, use xcopy /d in the main project's post-build event.

Comment: Does it resolve your quesiton? Please consider answering it and accepting it as  an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).